# Renaming files of a specific folder with numbering (script)

Tags: batch-file, rename

I need to rename all files in a folder with numbering, for example - i got 4 files (test.txt test(1).txt test.doc test(1).doc) and i need to rename them to name1.txt name2.txt name3.doc name4.doc

im currently trying this script but it does not work properly

```
@ECHO off

for /L %%n in (1,1,10) do rename D:\folder\*.* name%%n.*

end
```

any advices? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
pushd c:\someDir
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /a counter=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *') do (
    set /a counter=counter+1
    ren "%%~nxa" "NAME!counter!%%~xa"

)
endlocal
```

Comment: Almost works but should be for any file, not just .doc or .txt and should change it's name to "NAME1.txt" not the current name.